# Is it possible to pass a value to a YAML list?

Tags: ruby, list, yaml, haml, enumerable

I'm looking for a way to pass a value to a list enumerable, so I could produce a set of list items for a <ul>. The value should be displayed by the item that allows it.

- new
- favorites (15)           <-- 15 being the value I want displayed.
- archived
- deleted

The following does not work as is, but should help illustrate the goal to achieve.

**HAML**

```
%ul
  =list_of t('.menu', favorites_count: 15) do |item|
    #{item}
```

**YAML**

```
menu:
  - new
  - favorites ('%{favorites_count}')
  - archived
  - deleted
```

Note: initially I had my YAML include the <li> tags in a dictionary form, inside strings, one of which includes the count value.  But I find it a bit clumsy to mix HTML and YAML, like so:

```
menu:
  first_item: <li>new</li>
  second_item: <li>favorites %{favorites_count}</li>
  third_item: <li>archived</li>
  fourth_item: <li>deleted</li>
```

Hence looking for a cleaner option, that will only render tags on the HAML side and not litter them in YAML.

Comment: Is there a reason not to do this in, say, a partial? What do you gain by putting this in YAML?

Comment: A partial, I think it is a bit overkill.

Comment: @Jordan I have multiple other "menus" lists to load with variable number of items per menu and always different names, so I would need to create keys for each of them too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`I18n.t` uses interpolation syntax very similar to `sprintf`'s, which you can use to your advantage:

```
%ul
  = list_of t(".item") do |item|
    = sprintf(item, favorites_count: 15)
```

I'm not entirely sure that's the right Haml syntax, but you get the idea.

Comment: Good stuff, managed to shorten it a bit:
= "#{item}" % { favorites_count: 15 }

Comment: Don't do `"#{item}"`. `#{...}` is for string interpolation, but you're not interpolating anything here. If you know `item` is a string, just use `item`. If you're not sure it's a string, use `item.to_s`. In other words, do `= item % ...` or `= item.to_s % ...`. `"#{...}"` is always needless.